# Unable to simultaniously satisfy constraints - how do i know which ones conflict

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

How do i know which constraints conflict ?

```
2014-10-26 12:31:55.713 MyApp[17769:2430918] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79646340 V:[UIImageView:0x796475f0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79641bc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x796463a0 V:[UILabel:0x79636150'my settings']-(19)-[UIImageView:0x796475f0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79646430 V:|-(20)-[UILabel:0x79636150'my settings']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79641bc0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79640030 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x79641bc0.height == _UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView:0x79639c70.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7963a190 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[_UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView:0x79639c70(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x796463a0 V:[UILabel:0x79636150'my settings']-(19)-[UIImageView:0x796475f0]>
```

Comment: Looks like the error is telling you the table footer view has a height of 0 pixels tall but your [UIlabel]-19-[imageView] is conflicting with it.

Comment: Hi can you please add image for which the constraints is breaking. And also how you have set layout constraints.

Comment: Hi can you please tell how you have set the constraints and what is the height of the table footer view. It is saying that it is trying to set view by breaking 'V:[UILabel:0x79636150'my settings']-(19)-[UIImageView:0x796475f0]>' as it's not getting appropriate height. So can you please note down the height of table footer view and how you've set constraints.

Comment: the height of the footer is defined at runtime with a delegate method and it matches the height given in the xib file

Answer (score 0):

First let me say fixing these are not easy. I create most things in IB, so my usual approach is to clear all constrains and rebuild them.

In your case, you may have an easier answer. One of the constrains is `<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79640030 …`. This makes me suspect a view was added dynamically. Find that view.

Set [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) to `NO` before calling `-addSubview:` ([see](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html)).

At this point (hopefully) the view will load, but you're not done yet. They dynamically added view will be unconstrained. You will need to programmatically add any needed constraints [see](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1).

Comment: all my views were added in interface builder, the given view is a label that i added in the interface builder. If i remove and rebuild the constraints, some other constraint gets the complaint :(

Comment: @LenaBru If all your views are added in IB, then you should be getting warnings in IB about constraint issues.